# WordPress: function trashs post type with a new copy of the post

Tags: php, wordpress, cron, custom-post-type

I'm using the following function to trash a custom post type for events.
After an event took place, I delete the trash manually.

I found out, that the posts are still published after they should be deleted. The Version in the trash seems to be a new copy (with a new ID) of the original post?

Is there anything in the function which may produce such an error?

Here is my script:

```
<?php
    function get_delete_old_events() {

    $past_query = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 day'));
    // WP_Query arguments
    $args = array(
        'fields'         => 'ids', // Only get post ID's to improve performance
        'post_type'      => array( 'event' ), //post type
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',//fetch all posts,
        'meta_query'     => array(
            'relation'      => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'       => 'gid_22',
                    'value'     =>  $past_query,
                    'compare'   => '<='
                 )
        )
    );

    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            // do something
            $headers[] = 'From: Mail <mail@example.com>';

            $postid     = get_the_ID();
            $post       = get_post($postid);
            $author     = get_userdata($post->post_author);
            $subject    = "subject....: ".$post->post_title."";

            $message = "..."
;

            wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
            wp_trash_post( $id );
            // Also tried with this: 
            // wp_trash_post( $postid );
        }
    } else {
        // no posts found
        return false;

    }

    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();

}

// expired_post_delete hook fires when the Cron is executed
add_action( 'old_event_delete', 'get_delete_old_events' );


// Add function to register event to wp
add_action( 'wp', 'register_daily_events_delete_event');

function register_daily_events_delete_event() {
    // Make sure this event hasn't been scheduled
    if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'old_event_delete' ) ) {
        // Schedule the event
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'old_event_delete' );
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake... I'm setting the ID of the post as `$postid` and using `$id` instead...

Answer (score 1):

If you click the trash link then by default Wordpress will keep it for 30 days before permanently deleting it.

`wp_trash_post` moves an item to the trash if the 30 days havent passed and deletes it if they have, so it's working as I would expect it.

If you want to permanently delete a file straight away use `wp_delete_post($post_id, true);`

Comment: OK, so the empty trash button doesn't really empty it immediately? should I change `wp_trash_post( $id );` to `wp_delete_post($post_id, true);`

Comment: It only deletes it permanently if you then go into the trash and click the delete permanently link. If your post id is in variable `$id` then `wp_delete_post($id, true);` will permanently delete it straight away

Comment: OK, but I've permanently deleted alle posts. the trash was completely empty?! and the posts appear again in the trash without any published post is deleted

Comment: Ah, and there is another problem...  `wp_delete_post();` only works with native post types :(